# Not receiving some mail, possibly due to DNS misconfig?

Tags: postfix, amazon-web-services, dovecot, godaddy

I have an Ubuntu12.04 server running on Amazon AWS, and have a domain purchased from godaddy.com
I have setup a mail server with Postfix and Dovecot.
I am able to recieve most mails from senders. But some users are not able send mails to my domain. Almost all of these users who are not able to send mails are users with username@gmail.com accounts. However, many other Gmail users are able to send mails, including me.
Also, when a sender is not able to send the mail, he/she doesn't recieve a bounce and nothing is logged in mail.log for that email address

I am really lost as to what the problem may be. My guess is that the domain name is not configured properly. I have pointed MX and CNAME to @. @ is pointing to my server IP address.

Comment: Madhavan, I very strongly recommend that you be specific in your question; give the domain name, give an example of a bounce received by a gmail user, that sort of thing.  Although some people love to redact identifiable information in these questions, I urge you not to do that.  We are much more likely to be able to shed light on a question like '*why does serverxyz.amazonaws.com generate a "45x MX points to myself" error when receiving email from foo@gmail.com*?' than we are on one such as '*my mail doesn't go through, why not?*'.

Comment: The domain is slimpotato.com
The problem is the users donot get any bounce back, but their mails dont reach the server either.

Comment: Also my aws domain is ec2-54-214-143-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com, when a mail is sent to user@ec2-54-214-143-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com : the mail is recieved. but a mail sent to slimpotato.com, which points to the same IP, fails

Comment: It is very unusual for a mail simply to be dropped on the floor, particularly from someone like google.  Have you looked at your mail logs when a test is sent from gmail, to make sure that you're not receiving it?

Comment: I just tried sending an email by telnet'ing directly to your server. The mail is addressed to postmaster and I got the response `250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 0750D23683`. Could you check your mailserver logs and see if there's anything weird going on there?

Comment: I've also sent a second mail through a mailserver that I can control. That mail seems also to get delivered: `D9B5639848: to=<postmaster@slimpotato.com>, relay=slimpotato.com[54.214.143.226]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0/0.01/0.67/0.42, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 1D5F123683)`

Comment: Infact i got a very late bounce (24 hrs later):


This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:

   test@slimpotato.com

Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
DNS Error: DNS server returned general failure

Comment: Here's a possibility: your DNS provider is multihomed, and the server closest (topologically) to gmail is having problems. Contact your DNS provider, give them the entire error message, and explain that someone from Sweden has no problems sending you mail but gmail does.

Answer (score 1):

You may believe that your MX record is correctly defined, but from where I sit, it looks odd:

```
[me@risby]$ dig mx slimpotato.com
[...]
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;slimpotato.com.            IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
slimpotato.com.     3498    IN  MX  10 slimpotato.com.
slimpotato.com.     3498    IN  MX  0 slimpotato.com.
```

I confess that I'm not sure what effect listing the same server twice, with different weights, will have, and I can't yet find anything in [RFC 974](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc974) to clarify the question.  It is certainly ineffective, and you should probably remove the lower-weight record (the one with preference 10).

Secondly, as I said in a comment above, why are you certain that the mail isn't being delivered to you; have you got server logs when a test email is sent from gmail?

Comment: yes, the mail is not getting logged on mail.log.
I have posted a very late bounce from gmail which i have added as a comment above.

Comment: I also removed the MX record as you said, but the problem remains.